# Samba 4 `wbinfo` missing on CentOS

Tags: samba, samba4

I have installed samba4.x86_64 and the samba4-winbind using yum.  The `wbinfo` command is not present anywhere on the box.

Is there an alternative to `wbinfo` in Samba4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install:

```
samba4-winbind-clients
```